# mongodb statefulset pods restarting without any useful error during replication

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, replication, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset

I am trying to run a mongodb statefulset on minikube with replication but the pods keep restarting without any apparent reason. I have searched all over trying to debug this issue. Following is my statefulset and I am using NFS for PVC(this is for testing only).

MongoDB pod logs: https://www.toptal.com/developers/paste-gd/e1C6l8k2

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongodb
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        #lifecycle:
        # postStart:
        #   exec:
        #     command: ["/bin/sh","-c","mongosh -u $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME -p $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD< /tmp/init.js"]
        args: ["--config","/etc/mongod.conf","-vvv"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mongodb-data
          mountPath: /data
        - name: init-scripts
          mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        - name: keys
          mountPath: /keys
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/mongod.conf
          subPath: mongod.conf
        - name: repinit
          mountPath: /tmp/initscripts/
        env:
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongoadmin
                key: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongoadmin
                key: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      volumes:
      - name: init-scripts
        configMap:
          name: dbfiles
      - name: keys
        secret:
          secretName: dbkey
          defaultMode: 0400
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: dbconfig
      - name: repinit
        configMap:
           name: repinit

  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mongodb-data
    spec:
      accessModes: ["ReadWriteMany"]
      storageClassName: nfs-csi
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
```

k get pods

```
NAME        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
mongodb-0   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   3 (16s ago)     2m8s
mongodb-1   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7 (2m15s ago)   25m
mongodb-2   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7 (2m16s ago)   25m
nginx       1/1     Running            0               28h
```

k describe pod mongodb-0

```
Name:             mongodb-0
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             minikube/192.168.59.103
Start Time:       Sat, 17 Feb 2024 17:57:28 +0530
Labels:           app=mongodb
                  controller-revision-hash=mongodb-5dc867c4c7
                  statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=mongodb-0
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               10.244.0.76
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.76
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/mongodb
Containers:
  mongodb:
    Container ID:  docker://168537febead9f2c220e413174a7ab0710b4f1f5268a0ff23c74b19a5b98d3f3
    Image:         mongo:4.4.18
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://mongo@sha256:d23ec07162ca06646a6329c452643f37494af644d045c002a7b41873981c160d
    Port:          27017/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      --config
      /etc/mongod.conf
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sat, 17 Feb 2024 18:01:51 +0530
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Sat, 17 Feb 2024 18:00:06 +0530
      Finished:     Sat, 17 Feb 2024 18:00:25 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  5
    Environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:  <set to the key 'MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME' in secret 'mongoadmin'>  Optional: false
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD' in secret 'mongoadmin'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /data from mongodb-data (rw)
      /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d from init-scripts (rw)
      /etc/mongod.conf from config (rw,path="mongod.conf")
      /keys from keys (rw)
      /tmp/init.js from repinit (rw,path="init.js")
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-lpq4q (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  mongodb-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  mongodb-data-mongodb-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  init-scripts:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      dbfiles
    Optional:  false
  keys:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  dbkey
    Optional:    false
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      dbconfig
    Optional:  false
  repinit:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      repinit
    Optional:  false
  kube-api-access-lpq4q:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  4m32s                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mongodb-0 to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     119s (x5 over 4m27s)  kubelet            Container image "mongo:4.4.18" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    117s (x5 over 4m27s)  kubelet            Created container mongodb
  Normal   Started    114s (x5 over 4m26s)  kubelet            Started container mongodb
  Warning  BackOff    50s (x10 over 3m48s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container mongodb in pod mongodb-0_default(14ff7d3c-e08a-47c4-828b-928cd017bd50)
```

Additionally, this setup works fine if I remove the config parameter.

Following is the init script for reference. I only want it to run on first pod of the statefullset.

```
const user = process.env["MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME"]
const pass = process.env["MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD"]
db = connect('mongodb://'+user+':'+pass+'@localhost/admin');
let i = 0;
//var file = cat('/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/users.json');
var file =  fs.readFileSync('/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/users.json', 'utf8' )
var myusers = JSON.parse(file);
while (i < myusers.length) {
        if (db.getUser(myusers[i].user) == null) {
                db.createUser(myusers[i]);
        }
        i++;
}

db = db.getSiblingDB("testdb1");
if (db.test.countDocuments({}) == 0) {
        var datastr =  fs.readFileSync('/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db1.json','utf-8')
        var data = JSON.parse(datastr)
        db.test.insertMany(data)
}
db = db.getSiblingDB("testdb2")
if (db.test.countDocuments({}) == 0) {
        var datastr =  fs.readFileSync('/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db2.json')
        var data = JSON.parse(datastr)
        db.test.insertMany(data)
}
```

mongod.conf

```
replication:
  replSetName: "rs0"
security:
  keyFile: /keys/key

storage:
  dbPath: /data/db

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

Comment: Can you share your init script?
Line 138 of the logs shows that mongod receives a signal to shutdown. 
From the MongoDB-Enterprise YAMLs I know that their init-Script is loaded via initcontainer and not arguments. - This would be my first guess.
Or have you tried to define a (fake) livenessprobe so kubernetes knows that the pod is ok?

Comment: According to your logfile you did not enable authentication, thus creating all the users and keyfile does not make much sense. And why do you use an almost outdated version of MongoDB?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit My minikube is not supporting AVX and this version seems to be the highest which can run without AVX. I have Hyper-V running and somehow it is interfering with virtualbox not able to provide AVX for guest VMs. Let me run it with Authentication to see if it works.

Comment: @A.Copter I added my init script for your reference but honestly it runs fine wether I provide mongod.conf or not

Comment: Then it might be a good idea to provide also the `mongod.conf` file

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  I think there is some issue with the replication. When I run the statefulset with --replSet option, the pods keep crashing. Other options like --auth do not cause the crash. I shared config file for your reference

Comment: I don't see any `rs.initiate()`. A replica set must be initated. Does `fs.readFileSync` work in `mongo` legacy shell? The old `mongo` shell is not a full Node.js environment like the new `mongosh`. Consider to load scripts with `load()`

Comment: The rs.initiate() is executed from init.js script during postStart hook. I changed to the latest mongo image after resolving the AVX issue in minikube but the issue is still there.To isolate the issue, I removed the postStart hook but still the pods kept crashing.. Anyways, I resolved the issue and it seems my keyFile permissions were incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. My keyfile permissions were incorrect. MongoDB requires keyfile to be 400 and be owned by mongodb(uid: 999). This turned out to be a [challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945437/changing-default-file-owner-and-group-owner-of-kubernetes-secrets-files-mounted) as there seems to be no way to change the owner of any file mounted through a configmap/secret.

Answer (score 0):

In your script I see a few point which **could** be problematic, however I did not test whether they really cause any errors:

Why do you use `connect(...)`? I would assume, when you run the script, then you are already connected to the database.

When you enable authentication, then authentication becomes active in that moment when you created the first admin user. That means after command `{"createUser": "mongoadmin", ...}` you must use [db.auth()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.auth/) before you can continue. Otherwise all commands will fail with "authentication required" error. However, I have no clue about kubernetes, thus I don't know when and where the first admin/roor user is created.

I think `db` is a reference to your current database. You should not overwrite it. Better use

```
testdb1 = db.getSiblingDB("testdb1");
testdb1.test.countDocuments({}) ...
```

or directly

```
db.getSiblingDB("testdb1").test.countDocuments({})
```

There is no reason to pass the script to STDIN, i.e. `mongo < /tmp/init.js`. The mongo shell can run shell scripts. Simply use `mongo /tmp/init.js --username username --password ...`, then you also don't have any headache with quotes or escape sequences.

Does your password contain any special characters? It most not contain `: / ? # [ ] @`. Use `encodeURI(pass)` to escape these characters.

Comment: I did some debugging but the issue persists. Earlier I was using a very old version of Mongo due to AVX not available in my minkube so first I fixed that and re-ran the setup with the latest image. I rewrote the scripts for the newer version and even disabled initialization but still the pods restart. I have shared the mongod.conf and updated the link having fresh logs